# How to decide WorldSize ,viewport for GamePlay and HUD

Tags: android, ios, mobile, libgdx, game-development

I am making a game ,having static gameplay(i.e fixed background).
I want to target devices having aspect ratio in range **1.33(800x600) to 1.77(854x480)**.
For my playArea i want a fixed aspect ratio. 
For my HUD i want fixed position relative to Scrren Size
and i am using stages to implement HUD,gameplay area.

- **Note** Here World Size refers to virtual size (as mentioned by **[Springrbua](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3182091/springrbua)**)

**First Question**- is that possible to target wide range of screens with constant **worldsize** or setting some ViewPort-(Stretch,Fill etc) ?

**Second Question** - what should be the world size in pixel so that i can create graphics acc to it?

**Third Question** - what should be viewport for HUD,Gameplay ?

My Experience...
I started a game with **WorldSize (855 x 600)** and **Fill ViewPort** for gamePlay and **StretchViewPort** for HUD.For gameplay so far is good , but i am facing many problems with HUD.Position of hud elements never reamain same whatever i do(fixed position irrespective of screenSize).

**Last One** - Is creating background of resolution **855x600** is right thing to do?

Plz suggests better alternative ,approach or what i am doing wrong.

Thanks in Advance.

sry for my bad english.

Comment: might be a little out of scope for StackOverflow. If you continue to work with libgdx then I'd suggest to stop by at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ that might generate more attention.

Comment: can i shift this post to  gamedev.stackexchange.com.?

Answer (score 3):

First of all: the world size is not the same as the viewport size (or virtual size in the text below):
Worldsize: Size of the level
Virtual size: Size of the levelpart/worldpart you can see on screen

Usually you can only see a part of the level and a `Camera` moves arround to show different parts.
If the whole level is shown on the screen at once, the worldsize and the virtual size are the same.
To keep everything as simple as possible, they should use the same units (for example meters).

With libgdx it is not only possible to have a fixed virtual size, but it is also pretty easy.

As you allready noticed, there are the `Viewport` classes, some of them support a virtual size to.
The `Viewport` you should use for your gameplay area is the `FitViewport`, which supports virtual size and keeps the aspect ration by showing black borders (for example a 16:9 aspect ration on a 16/10 screen will result in black borders on the top and on the bottom of the screen).
For the HUD you can use another `Viewport`, i guess `StretchViewport` is okay. It also supports virtual sizes, but instead of keeping the aspect ratio it stretches the things (for example the elements of a 16:9 virtual aspect ratio on a 16/10 screen will be stretched up and down) to fill the screen.

The virtual size you want to choose depends on the game. Just think about it this way:

1. What entities are there on screen? For example **Humans**.
2. How big are they in real life? **Humans** are about 1.75m tall.
3. How big do i want them to be on screen? A **Human** should be about 1/10 of the screen.

Okay, now you have 1.75m should be 1/10 screenheight. Therefore the Screensize is `1.75*10=17.5`.
To have it a bit simpler, lets guess we have a bit taller (1.8m) **humans** and so our virtual height is now **18**.

Now think about the Aspect ratio, i want a 16/9 aspekt ratio, which means, that `16/9 = width/*18*`
Our virtual width is **32**.
Now we have a virtual size of **32*18m**. The bigest advantage: Everything can now be calculated in meters. If you want to move the **human** by 1m, just add 1 to its position.

As i allready said the `Viewport`s can be `FitViewport` for the game, as you want to keep the aspect ratio and for the HUD i guess `StretchViewport` would be fine, but you can try out different ones and choose your preffered.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for quick reply . instead of meter can u tell me in pixel since my game is not real world,it is hard to assuming size in meter and all that.Virtual size in pixel and background graphics resolution size? i think fillview is better option than fitview ,no one like black bars..

Comment: `FillView` uses up the whole screen, but as much as i know then other aspect rations see less of the screen, which results in disadvantages for them. In some games this is okay, in some may not. In Pixels is pretty hard, as you are targeting different resolutions, on different devices the gameplay would be different. You can choose some resolutions you want to support and let the user select them in settings. Then create the viewport with the selected resolution in mind

Comment: This answer is pure gold. Thanks for this.